# matplotlib modified color map with white as zero

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

Some of the standard `matplotlib` `cmap`s, such as `viridis` or `jet` show dark colors in **small values**. While this is what I need, I like them to show nothing, i.e. white background if the value is **exactly zero**. For non zero values the usual colors of that color map are fine.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would rather mask zero out of your data, e.g. setting those values to `nan` or use a masked array. Then you can just `set_bad("white")` for your colormap.

Comment: thanks. works like a charm! But just one last (maybe a bit general) question. Is generally masking faster (i.e. `zz = np.ma.masked_where(zz < 0.2, zz)`) or assigning NaN (i.e. `zz[zz<0.2] = np.NaN`) for large matrices? e.g.

Comment: I don't actually know. I would guess setting elements to `nan` is faster than using the `ma` arrays. But then again, when plotting you are mostly concerned with the draw time and not drawing masked arrays may be as fast as not drawing nans. The IPython `%timeit` magic is a good thing to find out for yourself.